# Can I create a script to test if i can use SSH and PING commands on a server remotely in python?

Tags: python, linux, networking, ssh

Can I create a script to test if i can use SSH and PING commands on a server remotely in python ?

Comment: you can use `paramiko`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's an example with Python3 and Linux. Just keep in mind that your target host/server must be running an SSH server in order to SSH onto that machine.

Also there are many other ways to do this... the built in socket module can also be used.

I am using a try/except to test the connection and whether or not SSH to the given host is possible. Also keep in mind that if your IP address or username/password are incorrect then the exception will also be caught.

Here's one way to ping a host:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> cmd = ['ping', '-c', '5', '192.168.0.13']
>>> x = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> x
b'PING 192.168.0.13 (192.168.0.13) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms\n64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms\n64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms\n64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms\n64 bytes from 192.168.0.13: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms\n\n--- 192.168.0.13 ping statistics ---\n5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4091ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.028/0.031/0.035/0.002 ms\n'
```

And here's an example of SSH with Paramiko (yes the port should be an int):

```
import paramiko
import sys

username = ''
password = ''
command = 'ls -l'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    ssh.connect("192.168.0.13", 22, username, password)
except Exception as e:
    print("unable to SSH: %s" % e)
    sys.exit()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
output = stdin.read()
ssh.close()
print(output)
```